# When I run my code I'm getting this error: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, response

Here is my code snippet.

```
class IndexResource(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        headers ={'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
    return 
make_response(render_template('main.html'), 200, headers)

class AddStudent(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
    return
make_response(render_template('addStudent.html'), 200, headers)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `return`s? Did you mean for them to be inside of the methods, and to be `return headers`? As the error says, you can't have returns outside of functions, and with your current indentation, they are indeed outside of any functions.

Comment: Because badly indented python code is invalid python code. The indentation of your line tells the interpreter what block the line is in. In your case, the `return` lines are indented to the same level as the `def`, which means they are not inside the function definition. This is one of the first things you learn in a python tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statements need to align vertically with the `headers` line.  Not sure what this code should do but this will fix the syntax error.

```
class IndexResource(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        headers ={'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        return 
make_response(render_template('main.html'), 200, headers)

class AddStudent(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        return
make_response(render_template('addStudent.html'), 200, headers)
```

Comment: I'm new to python so most of the errors I am getting are caused by the bad indentation. It worked thank you

Comment: To auto fixes the indentation error, you can use some Python editor, preferably Pycharm which will auto fix these issues.

Comment: If you use an empty `return` you will need no `return` at all.